# PHP5.3.8 and Apache2.4 start under the xampp environment

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp

I'd like to make `PHP5.3.8` and `Apache2.4` start under the `windows 64bit` and the `xampp` environment, when `apache_start.bat` is performed by *command pronto*, the following error occurs, and `Apache` can't be started.

```
C:\xampp>apache_start.bat
Diese Eingabeforderung nicht waehrend des Running beenden
Bitte erst bei einem gewollten Shutdown schliessen
Please close this command only for Shutdown
Apache 2 is starting ...
httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 187 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf:
Cannot load C:xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll into server:
\x8ew\x92\xe8\x82\xb3\x82\xea\x82\xbd\x83\x82\x83W\x83\x85\x81[\x83\x8b\x82\xaa\x8c\xa9\x82\xc2\x82\xa9\x82\xe8\x82\xdc\x82\xb9\x82\xf1\x81B

Apache konnte nicht gestartet werden
Apache could not be started
```

The one which is the cause checked the error contents, and found out that *binary* of `PHP` and `Apache` doesn't match.
So the following command was carried out and *binary* of `PHP` and `Apache` was checked.

```
C:\xampp > cd C:\xampp\apache\bin
C:\xampp\apache\bin > httpd -v

Server version: Apache/2.4.41 (Win64)
Apache Lounge VC15 Server built:   Aug 11 2019 12:20:04

C:\xampp\apache\bin > cd C:\xampp
C:\xampp > php -r "echo PHP_INT_SIZE;"

4
```

When the investigation was continued on the Internet, when it could be settled when [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=30679) was installed, I had that, so `x64` added to the Windows was installed, but it couldn't be settled.

**I'd like to tell me the way which can start `PHP5.3.8` and `Apache2.4` by the environment of such `windows 64bit` and `xampp`.**

I worked by the following procedure.

1. Installation of PHP5.3.8

   `xampp-win32-1.7.7-VC9.zip` is downloaded from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/1.7.7/).

   `php` of `xampp-win32-1.7.7-VC9.zip\xampp`, change the name to `php53` and keep after `C:\xampp\`.
2. Movement of `httpd-xampp.conf`

   `xampp-win32-1.7.7-VC9.zip\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`, change the name to `httpd-xampp.cof53` and keep after `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\`.
3. List itemInstallation of `php5apache2_4.dll`.

   `php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.3-win32.zip` is downloaded from [Apache Additional downloads](https://www.apachelounge.com/download/additional/).

   I move `php5apache2_4.dll` of `php5apache2_4.dll-php-5.3-win32.zip\PHP 5.3.10\` to `C:\xampp\php53\`.

   And *line 18* of the `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf53` are changed to `LoadModule php5_module "/xampp/php/php5apache2_4.dll"` from `LoadModule php5_module "/xampp/php/php5apache2_2.dll"`.
4. Edit of `httpd.conf`.

   The following contents are added to `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf`.

```
# Dynamic Shared Object  For LoadModule crowd who has that in (DSO) Support (line 187).
LoadModule php5_module "C:PHP/php5apache2_4.dll"

# In the <IfModule mime_module>, (line 450,451)
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

# Most, the bottom
PHPIniDir "C:/xampp/php"
```

5. Edit of `php.ini`

   `php.ini` of `C:\xampp\php`, the name is changed to `php.ini - origin`.

   And, `php.ini - develop`, the name is changed to `php.ini`, `; extension_dir ="ext"`,under the `extension_dir = "C:\xampp\php\ext"` is added.
6. Making of a *symbolic link*.

   `C:\xampp\php`, the name is changed to `php - origin`.

   `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf`, the name is changed to `httpd-xampp.conf - origin`.

   And a *symbolic link* is made by the next command.

```
cd C:\xampp
mklink C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf53
mklink /D C:\xampp\php C:\xampp\php53
```

**Thank you.**

Answer (score 0):

Nr.1 if you load stuff from xampp/php you need to place it there and not in php53.

Nr.2 your httpd.conf looks broken to me. I wouldn't try to load the PHP module from there again as it's already being loaded by the distinct PHP config file. But even if you do you should make sure to use a valid path:

`C:PHP/php5apache2_4.dll`
Is not a valid path on Windows. There needs to be a slash (`/`) behind the `:`.
But even if there was a slash, you never mentioned there being a `C:\PHP` folder on your system. So far you only ever mentioned the `C:\xampp` and `C:\xampp\php` and `C:\xampp\php53` folders.

If removing the LoadModule statement alltogether doesn't help, maybe try entering a valid path instead. (Replacing the Windows-typical backslash with a forward-slash is definitely inteneded and should be kept that way when changing the path inside the httpd.conf or any other Apache/PHP config files.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question.
I tried not only your point but also other articles, but I could not solve it.
So I decided to try using CentOS.
Thank you very much for your polite answer.